# Error "Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources" on Phusion Passenger Docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, passenger, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy a Rails app using Docker and the [Phusion Passenger Ruby base image](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker), but whenever I try to access the app from the browser I get this error:

```
web_1 | [ 2016-02-08 04:18:44.6861 31/7ff292141700     age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application   /home/app/webapp: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
web_1 |   Error ID: d3103e16
web_1 |   Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-EwymlW.html
web_1 |   Message from application: <p>It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:</p>
web_1 |
web_1 |   <pre class="commands">bundle install</pre>
web_1 |
web_1 | <p>If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:</p>
web_1 |
web_1 | <ol>
web_1 |   <li>Is this app supposed to be run as the <code>app</code> user?</li>
web_1 |   <li>Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will
web_1 |       see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.</li>
web_1 | </ol>
web_1 |
web_1 | <p>-------- The exception is as follows: -------</p>
web_1 | Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
web_1 | <pre>  /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize&#39;
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!&#39;
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize&#39;
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs&#39;
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for&#39;
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs&#39;
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs&#39;
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup&#39;
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:127:in `setup&#39;
web_1 |   /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;&#39;
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require&#39;
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require&#39;
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem&#39;
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code&#39;
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler&#39;
web_1 |   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code&#39;
web_1 |   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app&#39;
web_1 |   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `&lt;module:App&gt;&#39;
web_1 |   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `&lt;module:PhusionPassenger&gt;&#39;
web_1 |   /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `&lt;main&gt;&#39;</pre>
web_1 |
web_1 |
web_1 | [ 2016-02-08 04:18:44.6935 31/7ff293143700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:277 ]: [Client 1-2] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is d3103e16. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby22:0.9.18

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Use baseimage-docker's init process.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

# Enable Nginx/Passenger
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down

# Enable portals virtual host
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY portals.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/portals.conf
RUN mkdir /home/app/webapp

# Load env vars into nginx
COPY rails-env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/rails-env.conf

# Install gems dependencies
COPY Gemfile* /tmp/
WORKDIR /tmp
RUN bundle install

# Copy rails app
WORKDIR /home/app/webapp
COPY . ./
RUN chown -R app:app ./

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

I tried running bundler as `RUN bundle install --deployment` but it didn't work as well. I am passing `RAILS_ENV` and `PASSENGER_APP_ENV` via the `rails-env.conf` file and they are both set to production (which is the default according to the Passenger image docs).

If I `docker exec -it bash <ID>` into the container and run `gem list` I see that all the gems are installed, so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: strange to have a `CMD` that is not close to the end of the Dockerfile

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ that's how the docs have it https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker#getting-started

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but be sure you update gem and bundler: `RUN gem update --system && gem update bundler`. Really you should update all the packages with `RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`.

Comment: It actually worked @ScottJacobsen, thanks! Send this as an answer and I will accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is due to out of date software. Because the passenger images are not updated frequently it is important to bring everything up to date in your `Dockerfile`. This is how I generally setup a `Dockerfile` based off a phusion image:

```
FROM phusion/passenger-ruby22:0.9.18

ENV SYSTEM_UPDATE=1
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get upgrade -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /home/app
COPY Gemfile /home/app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /home/app/Gemfile.lock
RUN gem update --system && \
gem update bundler && \
bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 5

# The rest of your app setup here

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/my_init", "--"]
```

`SYSTEM_UPDATE` is just a cache buster variable. When I bump that up all the packages will be updated on the next docker build. It should be bumped frequently.

I also ensure `gem` and `bundler` are fully up to date before running `bundle install`.

Also, there is no benefit to copying your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` to the tmp directory, just copy it to your application directory.

You can remove your final `Clean up APT when done.` command - that's really not the right place for that. There should be a single `RUN` line that runs all the `apt-get` commands in a single layer.

Take a look at https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/ for the best practices around setting up a Dockerfile, especially the sections about using apt-get.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but I don't have an idea what's a Dockerfile. I just installed phusion passenger using `gem install passenger` and then `passenger-install-nginx-module`. How can I update passenger?

Answer (score -1):

For me, rake was there, I fix it using

`rake rails:update`

have fun!